# Configure gnome-terminal so that right click extends selection rather than displays menu

Tags: clipboard, selection, right-click, gnome-terminal

I've been using Linux for a long time, but have only recently 'upgraded' to a full GUI desktop since using it command-line-only for the last three or four years. I used to use 'aterm' before then (with fluxbox, and other old-school things) but I see now that gnome-terminal is pretty usable in Ubuntu's Gnome.

However, there's one thing that really gets me - when you select something and then right click, it doesn't extend the selection, instead it brings up a pop-up menu.

I've been using terminals and emacs for years and right-click has always extended a selection - so there must be some way to configure gnome-terminal to do this. This is a habit I'm not going to be able to grow out of because I use it all the time in emacs.

Does anyone have the magic recipe to restore the behaviour I'm after please?

Alternatively, what's a good and modern alternative to gnome-terminal?

I'm using Ubuntu 10.04.

Comment: I guess you're looking for the same behavior as Shift + LeftMouse button (extends selection)?

Comment: Here's an old (2002) bug report where this is "discussed": https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=93674 (my guess is that if you want this you'll have to patch GNOME Terminal yourself).

Comment: Shift + LeftMouse extends the selection, but it's horribly broken - try it and you'll see that the 'extra' selection doesn't get copied on paste (either middle-click or copy/paste). No good at all.

I've decided to drop gnome-terminal completely and I'm now enjoying rxvt-unicode, which has much saner selection behaviour.

Comment: You're absolutely right, it is indeed horribly broken...

Comment: Looks like that Shift+LeftMouse selection extension problem is fixed in at least gnome-terminal 3.4.1.1 (Ubuntu 12.04.1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @bruce-van-der-kooij rightly pointed out, the answer is to Shift+LeftMouseClick, which extends the selection.

Answer (score 1):

Try program called terminator.

```
sudo apt-get install terminator
```